# Asus x750j not allowing me to boot Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, asus

I have tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 multiple times on my Asus X750J laptop. I have already put it on some of my other computers. However, when I attempt to put it on this laptop, it will not work. I replaced the Hard drive that was in it with an SSD when I purchased it. I am able to boot Ubuntu from my USB, and attempt to install and go through the entire process, however, when I try booting up my machine, there is no option for Ubuntu and the partition I create for Ubuntu is not listed as one of my boot options. When I go through the install and get to the part where I create the root partition for Ubuntu, and click on Install now, there is a warning message that says something about a Reserve Bios Partition, so I tried making one, and then another warning came up as well, but I do not remember what it said. I can let you know if it is necessary. Please assist as soon as possible.